# How to dual boot windows after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, gpt, ubuntu-16.04, boot-partition

**I am trying to dual boot my laptop with windows 10 which already has Ubuntu 16.04 in it.**
So I made an unallocated partition for windows with gparted live CD and tried installing windows into that unpartioned data.
But during the windows installation process an error shows up saying that the disk is GPT partition style and so the windows cannot be installed to the disk.
How to solve this problem?
If I have to change my partition table type to `MBR` from `GPT`.
**How can I do it without loss of data and ubuntu**?

Comment: Does your system has UEFI firmware? Check it in bios settings. If that is, enable it

Comment: you're already on GPT so you can't converted it to GPT. If your PC is BIOS only you have to convert to MBR

Comment: I don't really know if my system has UEFI firmware. I checked the BIOS settings and all I could find is that **Legacy support is enabled**

Comment: There are even 2 boot orders UEFI and Legacy which are OS boot manager and Notebook hard drive respectively

Answer (score 0):

The Windows error message you describe is misleading, at least in the context in which you encountered it. Windows ties its boot mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI) to the boot disk's partition table type (MBR vs. GPT) quite tightly. The message you encountered indicates that the computer booted in BIOS mode but found a GPT disk, which confuses Windows, and it complains about the GPT disk. Because Ubuntu is already installed on the disk, though, changing it from GPT to MBR would be awkward -- Ubuntu would likely be rendered unbootable, at least until you installed a new boot loader. There might be other follow-on problems, too.

In all probability, the better solution is to bring the boot mode and partition table type into alignment by changing the boot mode -- that is, to boot the Windows installer in EFI mode rather than in BIOS mode. (There's one *big* caveat; see below.) Unfortunately, how to do this varies from one computer to another and may also depend on how you prepared the Windows installation medium. Some possibilities include:

- In most cases, you use the firmware's built-in boot manager to boot the Windows installer. This tool may have two options to boot the external medium, one of which includes the string "UEFI" and the other of which does not. Pick the option that includes "UEFI" to boot in EFI mode and solve the problem.
- You can enter the firmware setup utility and locate a boot options screen. On this screen, you should be able to adjust the boot mode to "UEFI only" or something similar. (It's probably set to "UEFI and legacy" or something along those lines.)
- You may need to re-create the boot medium, especially if you created a USB flash drive from a `.iso` file. Some tools to make this conversion omit the EFI boot loader, so switching tools, or at least selecting the right options, may be necessary.

Now, the big caveat: If your computer is old enough to use a true BIOS rather than an EFI, then it can't boot in EFI mode. BIOS-based computers were common prior to late 2011, but they've been rare since then. If you can find references to "EFI" or "UEFI" in the firmware setup utility, then it's almost certainly EFI-based. If not, and especially if the computer is from 2011 or earlier, then it may have an old-school BIOS. In this case, you have two options:

- **Convert the disk to MBR** -- You can use my `gdisk` (which comes with Ubuntu) to convert the disk from GPT to MBR. (See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr) of the `gdisk` documentation for information on how to do this.) The trouble with this, as I've said, is that Ubuntu will be rendered unbootable. You'll need to re-install GRUB, either manually or with the help of [Boot Repair,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to get Ubuntu booting again. You might want to put off the Ubuntu repair until after you install Windows, since installing Windows in BIOS mode will also damage GRUB. Also, note that you may need to shrink one or more partitions (by as little as one sector, although GParted will likely require a minimum of 1 MiB shrinkage), and you'll have to understand and carefully plan use of extended and logical partitions, at least if you will have over four partitions, once the Windows partition(s) are added. Unfortunately, the Windows partitioning tools deal poorly with MBR disks that have more than four partitions; those Windows tools tend to do things that are unfriendly to Linux on such disks. See [this question and its answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1205021/basic-disk-and-dynamic-disk-vs-primary-partition-and-extended-partition-and-log) for the gory details.
- **Use a hybrid MBR** -- A hybrid MBR is an ugly and dangerous hack that's most often used to enable Windows 7 or earlier to dual-boot on Macs alongside OS X/macOS. It could be useful in your situation, though, by enabling Windows to boot and think that the disk uses MBR, while not disturbing the GPT configuration used by Ubuntu too much. See [my page on hybrid MBRs](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) for more details. I ordinarily recommend against using hybrid MBRs, but if your computer really is BIOS-based, and if you'll have more than four partitions, I'm torn between recommending you convert to MBR and deal with the flaky Windows partitioning software or add a hybrid MBR and deal with its problems. They're both dangerous options, in all honesty.

I don't recommend converting your disk to use MBR, or a hybrid MBR, if your computer uses EFI firmware; installing Windows in EFI mode is a better option in this case. (Note that many people, and even computer manufacturers, refer to their EFIs as "BIOSes." This is inaccurate and confusing, but I suspect that manufacturers do it so as to avoid introducing yet another acronym to their customers -- a short-sighted decision, IMHO.)

Comment: Good news! Mine is not that old and has EFI boot option even though I don't know if that's how my lap is booted. So , coming to back to the first option- mine is a "HP Notebook AY078TX" a DOS machine (which caused this problem in the first place). Can you please clearly point out directions to how to boot the windows installer in EFI mode cause I'm really having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

Comment: And thanks for such an elaborate​ reply in no time.!

Comment: As I say, details vary from one computer to another, so I can't be more precise than I have been. You might find instructions in the computer's manual or on HP's site. Otherwise, you'll have to try to find the options I've already mentioned in my answer, although I don't know the exact names they're given in your computer's firmware.

Comment: I checked the BIOS settings and all I could find is that **Legacy support is enabled**. So I disabled it and tried booting through the USB flash drive containing windows. But this boot option from USB wasn't available ( Ubuntu was working​ fine).

Comment: There are even 2 boot orders UEFI and Legacy which are OS boot manager and Notebook hard drive respectively. Once I **disabled the legacy support** the latter also got disabled (kind of, it stopped being highlighted of sort).